# How to integrate Jscrollpage to popup content?

Tags: javascript, popup

I have a html page including popup. Popup contains basic contents. Due to pop contents exceeds the screen heights top section of popup window can't preview. Because of this I made a decision to use any javascript [scroll plugin](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/).

But I couldn't integrate between popup and scroll plugins.

What can I do ?

Demo : http://www.heptasarim.com/test/cezayir

PS : All the sections of popup contents is preview at the moment. But later it will be added several pictures.

Comment: I can't help you with your question, but I can suggest trying  a different scroll plugin; NiceScroll (http://areaaperta.com/nicescroll/). This might be a good alternative, it's very slick and works well with touch devices. (I'm just a fan, not trying to advertise)

Comment: Thank you very much Martjin. But I couldn't. I need someone who knows JS well.

Comment: I think you will get an answer if you explain more clearly what the problem is, I for one have no idea what you are asking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your question is how to add the jScrollPane to your popup, then 2 things:

1.) Set a height on your `<div id="ab-orta"></div>` like `#ab-orta{height:500px;}` (otherwise it will just expand)

2.) Call the jScrollPane function on your div with: `$('#ab-orta').jScrollPane();`